# Swift 5.2 crash compiler, protocol method reference

Tags: swift

The following code snippet crashes the Swift 5.2 compiler with a segmentation fault.

```
protocol Something {
    func add(_ n: Int)
}

let function = Something.add
```

What is the problem here?

Here is the stacktrace

```
1.  Apple Swift version 5.2.2 (swiftlang-1103.0.32.6 clang-1103.0.32.51)
0  swift                    0x000000011369f4ea PrintStackTraceSignalHandler(void*) + 42
1  swift                    0x000000011369ecc0 SignalHandler(int) + 352
2  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff6db7d5fd _sigtramp + 29
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007ffee08b1f48 _sigtramp + 1926449512
4  swift                    0x000000010f8885fa swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitOpenExistentialExprImpl(swift::OpenExistentialExpr*, llvm::function_ref<void (swift::Expr*)>) + 666
5  swift                    0x000000010f87979a swift::ASTVisitor<(anonymous namespace)::RValueEmitter, swift::Lowering::RValue, void, void, void, void, void, swift::Lowering::SGFContext>::visit(swift::Expr*, swift::Lowering::SGFContext) + 38938
6  swift                    0x000000010f86fd93 swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitExprInto(swift::Expr*, swift::Lowering::Initialization*, llvm::Optional<swift::SILLocation>) + 131
7  swift                    0x000000010f863c18 swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction::emitPatternBinding(swift::PatternBindingDecl*, unsigned int) + 280
8  swift                    0x000000010f80ec5d swift::ASTVisitor<swift::Lowering::SILGenFunction, void, void, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Decl*) + 109
9  swift                    0x000000010f8105f1 swift::ASTVisitor<swift::Lowering::SILGenModule, void, void, void, void, void, void>::visit(swift::Decl*) + 1265
10 swift                    0x000000010f80f31c swift::Lowering::SILGenModule::emitSourceFile(swift::SourceFile*) + 1356
11 swift                    0x000000010f81139e swift::SILModule::constructSIL(swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::Lowering::TypeConverter&, swift::SILOptions&, swift::FileUnit*) + 1438
12 swift                    0x000000010f3f1131 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 48065
13 swift                    0x000000010f368f53 main + 1283
14 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff6d984cc9 start + 1
15 libdyld.dylib            0x0000000000000045 start + 2456269693
error: Segmentation fault: 11
```

Comment: You can't assign a function variable from a protocol I believe, it needs to be from a struct or class. Besides you are accessing it like it is a static function.

Comment: You should report this at https://bugs.swift.org

Comment: I have reported it https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-12657

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is a know bug in the Swift 5.2 compiler. It should be fixed in Swift 5.3 with support for this pattern. See here https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-75